# android - connecting to web page with Jsoup

Tags: android, text, jsoup, html

I'm trying to grab some text from a webpage, from a div class named "text" with Jsoup. This is the part of the code where I'm trying to grab the content:

```
try {

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://website.com").get();
Elements div = doc.select["meta[class=text]");
String textString = div.toString();
}

catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run the activity, it shows an error in the line where I'm trying to connect. This is the content from the logcat.

> 03-17 14:30:34.270 23413-23413/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   03-17 14:30:35.170 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos I/View:
>   ssignParent(ViewParent parent) parent is:
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl@fc40abe 03-17 14:30:35.370
>   23413-23552/com.example.goliath.pomos I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized
>   EGL, version 1.4 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.example.goliath.pomos, PID: 23413 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:
>   android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1167)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418) 03-17
>   14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 03-17
>   14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 03-17
>   14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205) 03-17
>   14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194) 03-17
>   14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at
>   com.example.goliath.pomos.Koli.onNavigationItemSelected(Koli.java:120)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:150)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:153)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:300)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4768) 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19692) 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5538) 03-17
>   14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 03-17 14:30:37.580
>   23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
>   03-17 14:30:37.580 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos
>   E/AndroidRuntime:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:753) 03-17
>   14:30:37.610 23413-23413/com.example.goliath.pomos I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 23413 SIG: 9

This is my first time using Jsoup, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on the main thread. You should run your code in AsyncTask, or disable checks (bad choice):

**AsyncTask:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new ParsePageTask().execute("http://stackoverflow.com/");
    }

    class ParsePageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
                Elements div = doc.select("title");
                return div.toString();
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }

            return "";
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // process results
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**"Network on main thread" policy disable:**

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
...
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://website.com").get();
```

Also you should check internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved the problem and got the wanted text. One more quick question. Is there a way for me to format the text? Get the paragraphs like they are on the website? Everything now is right next to each other and it's hard to read. I only need to put blank row between them.

Comment: @user4505484 You can try to use **Html.fromHtml**: `textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p>First paragraph</p><p>Second paragraph</p>..."));`

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. In Android you can't use the Network in the main thread. You need to create an AsyncTask in ordedr to use the `Jsoup.connect(URL)` method.
2. If you want to select a `div` with the name attribute `text`, then you need to use `select(div[name=text])`. What you did, to select elements with a tag called meta and carrying exactly one class called `text`.